# Cannot declare global variable with the name of a struct

Tags: c

Struct members can use the same name as a type, but it appears that global variables cannot. Does anyone know why? I am using MinGW-64, an implementation of GNU C.

```
typedef struct foo{

}foo;

foo foo;

int main()
{

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Struct members have their own namespace. A global variable is in the same global namespace as the typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is fairly simple. You cannot redefine the meaning of a name in the same scope it is defined. To contrast, this would be valid

```
typedef struct foo{
  char c;
}foo;

int main()
{
    foo foo;
}
```

Following the declaration in the scope of `main`, the meaning of `foo` is altered. But when you do it in the same scope as the type alias, you are basically providing conflicting definitions.

Struct fields aren't in the scope of the type definition itself. So that's why those don't conflict either.

Comment: Member names were never part of the same name space as object and type names, to my memory, but they were all in one name space of structure and union member names, instead of separate name spaces for each structure or union.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Yeah, I figured I might be misremembering. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When compiled with `gcc`, this error is produced:

```
test.c:5:5: error: ‘foo’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 foo foo;
```

This is the issue. The statement `foo foo;` tries to re-declare the symbol `foo` as a variable when it has already been declared to refer to `struct foo`. You can fix your issue by changing the name of the variable to something else.

Comment: even with a typedef in the struct's declaration?

Comment: but my point was that in the example the struct is declared with a typedef, so it surprises me that you can't then do `foo foo;`

Comment: Other than not actually answering the question, this misses that in the OP's code they used a typedef along with the struct definition. Thus allowing the use of both `struct foo` and `foo`.

Comment: i feel vindicated :) @adrian , will you clarify, or perhaps delete the answer?

Comment: I am fairly certain the the typedef covers this. The code I posted in my question works perfectly if you replace "foo foo;" with "foo bar;".

On compiling the code above, I get an error stating "'foo' redeclared as different type of symbol.". Perhaps this might help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you can't declare a *variable* of the same name as its type? You can, when scoping permits. Also, `foo` is not a keyword.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Of course, if  scoping permits you can declare a variable of the same name as its type, but in the OP's situation it won't work since they both exist in the same scope.

Comment: @JohnFriendson The code will work if you change the name of the variable defined to something other than `foo`. Your issue is caused by the fact that you're redeclaring `foo` as something else in the same scope.

Comment: I suggest you tidy up your answer to say what you mean with precision. This is ultimately what many people will judge an answer upon.